# android static methods usage

Tags: android, static

I am developing an android application, In which I created one "SessionManager.java" which contains only static methods, in splash screen  Activity only, I am creating the instance for "SessionManager ", Because it is the
fist activity in app,  But in sometimes, I am getting null object reference ,
is it necessary  to instantiate Class in every activity ?

Sample code

```
public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

 public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public static void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public static void setMobile (String login_mobile) {
        editor.putString("mobile", login_mobile);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static String getMobile() {
        return pref.getString("mobile", "00");
    }
```

}

sometimes  in some activities , getMobile() method is returning null value, why ? can I check null value before return that ? please give me any suggestions, I stuck here.

Comment: why downvote ? please tell me

Comment: why you are creating instance of session manager? static methods can be accessed using class name

Comment: yes, but first we have to create instance once, for memory allocation

Comment: so you are saying you will access static method via instance?

Comment: I thought that there should be one instance for SessionManager class, so i created one instance in splash screen,  In remaining activities  I am using directly .

Comment: But , is it good practice that directly accessing method ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it for storing values in shared preference then do it like this

```
    public class AppSharedPreferences {

    private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
    private static AppSharedPreferences appSharedPrefrence;

    public AppSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    }

    public AppSharedPreferences() {

    }

    public static AppSharedPreferences getsharedprefInstance(Context con) {
        if (appSharedPrefrence == null)
            appSharedPrefrence = new AppSharedPreferences(con);
        return appSharedPrefrence;
    }

    public SharedPreferences getAppSharedPrefs() {
        return appSharedPrefs;
    }

    public void setAppSharedPrefs(SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs) {
        this.appSharedPrefs = appSharedPrefs;
    }

    public SharedPreferences.Editor getPrefsEditor() {
        return prefsEditor;
    }

    public void Commit() {
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public void clearallSharedPrefernce() {
        prefsEditor.clear();
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
    public void setUserId(String userid)
    {
        this.prefsEditor=appSharedPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("user_id", userid);
        prefsEditor.apply();
    }
    public String getUserId() {
        return appSharedPrefs.getString("user_id","");
    }
}
```

and then to use it in class do it like this way

```
appSharedPreferences=AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(ActivityLogin.this);
```

and then call your method using **appsharedPreferences.yourMethod();**